# Trouble understanding a paragaph in "A Course in Probability Theory" by Kai Lai Chung

Tags: probability-theory

The author says that the pair $ \{ S_1, S_\gamma \} $ forms a martingale by Theorem 9.3.5 since $ \{ S_{\gamma \wedge n}, n \in N_\infty \} $ is a bounded martingale. I fail to keep up with his line of thought.

The second confusion is that how could $E(S_{\gamma \wedge 1}) = E(S_1)$ implies $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(S_{\gamma \wedge n}) = E(S_1)$?

Theorem 9.3.4: Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two bounded optional r.v.'s such that $\alpha \leq \beta$. Then for any [super]martingale $\{X_n\}$, $\{X_\alpha, \mathcal{F}_\alpha; X_\beta, \mathcal{F}\}$ forms a [super]martingale.

Theorem 9.3.5: Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two arbitrary optional r.v.'s such that $\alpha \leq \beta$. Then the conclusion of Theorem 9.3.4 holds true for any supermartingale $\{X_n, \mathcal{F}_n; n \in N_\infty\}$.

$x \wedge y := \min\{x, y\}$

$\{S_n, n \in N_0\}$ be a random walk.

$\alpha := \min\{n \geq 1: S_n = -a\}, \beta := \min\{n\geq 1: S_n = b\}$, where $a$ and $b$ are strictly positve integers.

$\gamma := \alpha \wedge \beta$ making a finite optional r.v.

The whole relative context is posted below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should be able to explain the "kernel" of your question without copying so many pages of a textbook !

Comment: Sorry. I've I modified the problem description.